# Argument error: Invalid date for date field coming from jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the method definition as:

```
if elem_date > Date.today
return true
else 
return false
```

when I run this as validation, Im getting Argument error: Invalid date. This worked before moving the system from rails 2.3.5 to rails 2.3.18. Im using Jquery date plugin in the front end for date selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is discrepency in the format the date is getting validated. You can validate the date by explicitly setting the format using

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m/%d/%Y"
```

This can be replaced by any format you wish before comparing it with todate. This configuration can be moved into your environment file.